# Contiki os: Rime + IPv6

Tags: routes, ipv6, contiki

I have a wireless sensor network running RIME stack on contiki os. I wish to connect this network to the outside Internet (IPv6). My question is that whether Rime is compatible with IPv6? Because when I try to compile them i get conflicts between rime.c and sicslowmac.c files

thank you

Answer (score 0):

No Rime isn't IPv6 compatible. You've to remove from compilation the rime.c file if you want to use IPv6.

http://contiki.sourceforge.net/docs/2.6/a01795.html

Answer (score 0):

only ipv4 can over rime.

introduce a idea: make a ipv4 network over rime, then take one node as AP and which connect to a PC. in that PC you open a bridge: ipv4<==>ipv6.